# Writing a converter, design in OOP way

Tags: oop

I am designing a unit converter, that convert weight, length and volume.
I prefer to put this in a OOP way, however I am not sure about:

1.What should be the class: Converter? Type(Weight, length, volume)? or unit(Gallon, OZ, Meter..)?

2.Since the from and to is different for different type, I cannot have a method called "convert" to apply polymorphism, but is this True?

3.Please also design the driver code

4.the conversion is mostly one liner, does it worth to put it in a OOP 
framework?  I see OOP is the way to stay organized and flexible

Thank you.

This is what it looks like now:

```
ConverterBase(object) # with attributes type, from, to
    if type == 'weight':
        if from == 'kg' and to == 'lb':
            kg_to_lib
        elif from == 'lb' and to == 'g':
            lb_to_g
    if type == 'length':
        if from == 'mile' and to =='km':
            milt_to_km
        elif from == 'm' and to == 'feet':
            m_to_feet
    if type == 'volume'
        if from =='oz' and to == 'gallon':
            oz_to_gallon
        if from == 'liter' and to == 'oz':
            liter_to_oz
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach (Java):

```
interface AbstractUnitConverter<U> {
    double convert(double quantity, U unitFrom, U unitTo);
}

class WeightConverter implements AbstractUnitConverter<WeightConverter.Unit> {
    private static final double KG_TO_LB_FACTOR = 2.20462;

    @Override
    public double convert(double quantity, Unit unitFrom, Unit unitTo) {

        switch (unitFrom) {
            case kg:
                switch (unitTo) {
                    case kg:    return quantity;
                    case lb:    return KG_TO_LB_FACTOR * quantity;
                    default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            case lb:
                switch (unitTo) {
                    case kg:    return quantity / KG_TO_LB_FACTOR;
                    case lb:    return quantity;
                    default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    enum Unit {
        kg, lb;
    }
}

class LengthConverter implements AbstractUnitConverter<LengthConverter.Unit> {
    @Override
    public double convert(double quantity, Unit unitFrom, Unit unitTo) {
        // similar to weight
    }

    enum Unit {
        km, mile;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WeightConverter weightConverter = new WeightConverter();
    System.out.println(weightConverter.convert(60, Unit.kg, Unit.lb));
}
```